# Deprecate class to dictionary properties python

Tags: python, dictionary, oop, deprecated

In python, I have a class, one of it's attributes is some other class that holds data, like this:

```py
class A:
    class Params:
        def __init__(self):
            self.param1 = None
            self.param2 = None
            ...

    def __init__(self):
        self.parameters = self.Params()
```

This way, if anyone wants to change one of the parameters in `self.parameters` he can write `self.parameters.param1 = ...`.

I want to change the class `Params` that holds the parameters into a dictionary

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parameters = {
            'self.param1': None
            'self.param2': None
        }
```

This way if anyone wants to change anything he can write `self.parameters['param1'] = ...` instead. I've implemented this change (in a development branch) and it works. The problem is that other people use that code and if I make this change it will break their code (it's and simple fix, but still).

I wanted to know if there is any way I can make it so that if anyone writes in the old way (i.e. `parameters.param1 = ...`) it would still work but print a `DEPRECATED` message when he does, this way I can make a transition window where people go from the old way to the new way. The only way I came up with is if I change the name of the attribute I can keep the old code and add a `log.warning`, but I don't want to change the name of the attribute so if anyone can think of a way to do this it would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define make `Params` implement the mapping protocol, then produce deprecation warnings on attribute access.

```
class Params:
    def __init__(self):
        ...  # As before

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        # This check is optional, to prevent creating new attributes
        if not hasattr(self, key):
            raise ValueError(f"No such parameter {key}")
        setattr(self, key, value)

    __getitem__ = getattr

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        warnings.warn("Don't set attributes directly", DeprecationWarning)
        super().__setattr__(attr, value)

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        warnings.warn("Don't access attributes directly", DeprecationWarning)
        super().__getattribute__(self, attr)
```

Now your next version will support both techniques, but attribute access will raise the warning. In the version *after* that, you can get rid of the `Params` class.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parameters = {
            'param1': None
            'param2': None
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!! I actually just realized a similar way to do it (yours is better though ) where the class inherits from `dict` and I use `super` to initialize the class.

Comment: I have another question (that I can get around but with a non-elegant way). `hasstr` calls `__getattribute__` (I learned that the hard way :\) so whenever I set attributes correctly (i.e. `param['key'] = value`) I get the warning to not access attributes directly. Because I know all the attributes, I can do without the `hasstr` but I wonder if you have a solution for that. Thanks! again!

Comment: I didn't revise this question as I should have. I used `hasattr` before I anticipated overriding `__getattribute__` to provide a deprecation, and in hindsight I shouldn't be overriding `__getattribute__`. The only thing that comes to mind would be to define a descriptor whose `__get__` and `__set__` methods provide the deprecation warnings, instead of overriding `__setattr__` and `__getattribute__`.

Comment: I managed to get it to work, I did need to modify your code in several places. I'm still really glad since I got to learn about these magic functions :)

Comment: Feel free to update this answer (or even post a separate one of your own); I made a small fix regarding the source of `DeprecationWarning`, but this was entirely untested.